# Can I change the color of a cosmetic I buy off the Community Market?

Tags: team-fortress-2, steam-community-market

I am looking to buy *'Anger'*, the hoodie for the sniper from the community market. Once I buy it can I change the color or is the color I buy it as permanent?

Reason why is because I'm doing the smart decision and buying it for $2,00 instead of $7,50 in-game :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean will you be able to choose its color after you buy it, then no. It is the color you buy it as.

You will have to buy a paint can of whatever color you want and paint it.